# Can you play bluetooth and wired audio together pc

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth

Is it possible to play sound through my bluetooth speaker which is connected to the computer as well as my normal computer speakers? 
As when you connect to bluetooth it only plays through that as standard, thanks